# how do I check if the X509Certificate issuer is trusted?

Tags: java, security, ssl, https, x509certificate

I have an instance of X509Certificate in java and I need to check if the issuer is trusted?

thanks
gal

Comment: You really need to check the issuer or just trust the certificate issued by the issuer?

Comment: I need to write a method that checks if a X509Certificate has an trusted CA issuer

Comment: boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate certificat)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: @ITCuties: Can you please help me.. Please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184090/add-server-certificate-information-to-trust-manager-android-programmatically

Answer (score 2):

If you just have the certificate (out of context), you should build a certification path using the [Java PKI Cert. Path API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html). If it's within the context of SSL, you should be able to use a `TrustManager` and check it when using your `SSLContext`.

This will verify whether the certificate was issued by a CA you trust (or via one of its intermediate CAs perhaps).

You may also be interested in "[What data should I validate when validating X.509 certificates using Java?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9594/what-data-should-i-validate-when-validating-x-509-certificates-using-java)" (on Security.SE).

Comment: How to check using sslContext whether the certificate is trusted or not

Comment: @ManoharPerepa Get the array of `TrustManager`s from the `SSLContext`, use its first element and call `checkServerTrusted` using that cert and the certificate algorithm.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184090/add-server-certificate-information-to-trust-manager-android-programmatically @Bruno