# Reconstruct certification chain in android

Tags: android

My android app needs to login and scrap the data under this domain name (*.nkust.edu.tw).

The problem is that I found that the certificate installation of the server is not complete ([SSL Checker result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfa0m.png)). Since I am not the administrator of the server, I would like to ask if there is any way reconstruct the certification chain programmatically?

I've referenced [Add Server Certificate Information to Trust Manager Android Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184090/add-server-certificate-information-to-trust-manager-android-programmatically) but it seems slightly different from the problem I have.

I'm now using kotlin with ktor over http, which I know it's unsafe for passing login info, and when it comes to downloading some file like pdf, it'll throw "sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException".

Certifications (root, server, uca) can be obtained from the following URL: https://ssl2.twca.com.tw/NCWebSSL/search.htm?dns=*.nkust.edu.tw

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I use ssl pinning: https://ktor.io/docs/client-ssl.html

not sure if it's the right way to do, but it works.

```kotlin
class SslSettings(val context: Context) {
    fun getKeyStore(): KeyStore {
        // read file from res folder (keyStoreFile.jks)
        // generate .jks from .pem using keytool
        val keyStoreFile = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.keyStoreFile)
        val keyStorePassword = "Custom_Password".toCharArray()
        val keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType())
        keyStore.load(keyStoreFile, keyStorePassword)
        return keyStore
    }

    fun getTrustManagerFactory(): TrustManagerFactory? {
        val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
        trustManagerFactory.init(getKeyStore())
        return trustManagerFactory
    }

    fun getSslContext(): SSLContext? {
        val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
        sslContext.init(null, getTrustManagerFactory()?.trustManagers, null)
        return sslContext
    }

    fun getTrustManager(): X509TrustManager {
        return getTrustManagerFactory()?.trustManagers?.first { it is X509TrustManager } as X509TrustManager
    }
}
```

then

```kotlin
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    engine {
       https {
         trustManager = SslSettings(applicationContext.getTrustManager())
        }
    }
}
```